# Button click function for easy initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make it so I can easily initialize JQuery Ajax buttons.

This works fine:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#home").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/",
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            $("#content").html(data);
        },
        error: function(response) {
            alert("ERROR:" + response.responseText);
        }
    });
});

});
```

I'm trying to simplify the above process by making it into a function and tried the the following code. But it does not work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    LoadContent("#home", "/");
    LoadContent("#login", "/account/signin");
    LoadContent("#signup", "/account/create");
    LoadContent("#forgot", "/account/forgot-password");
});


function LoadContent(buttonID, url) {
    $(buttonID).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
                $("#content").html(data);
            },
            error: function(response) {
                alert("ERROR:" + response.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I think it has to do something with how .click(function(e){}) is setup. However I'm not very familiar with JQuery.

Comment: What do you mean by "It doesn't work" exactly?

Comment: Are those buttons loaded on the page statically or dynamically?

Comment: and what's up with all those returns?

Comment: @MiiinimalLogic: It's all dynamic. I'm using Laravel to generate the pages.

Comment: @mplungjan Not sure if you're trolling. It's test code.

Comment: No trolling. None of the return keywords belong there. Just remove them

Comment: **Dynamic**, as in, are the buttons generated after the page loads?

Comment: @PeterKA: As you can see in the code. I'm using $(document).ready(function() {}). So no, buttons exist before javascript.

Comment: Fair enough. Then can you either explain what you mean by *it does not work* or create a minimal jsfiddle?

Comment: @mplungjan: Everything works perfect. Looks like I just had to remove the returns. Thanks!

Comment: @PeterKA and OP, but it looks like you're only calling the method on doc.ready not adding the buttons.

  Is it the server side thats adding them (assuming laravel)?  In that case, they're always loaded before javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I would suggest.

- give all the buttons a common class, say `.ajax-button`
- give each button a `data-url` attribute and let that equal the target `ajax` url
- simplify your code to the following

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ajax-button').on('click', LoadContent);
});


function LoadContent(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: $(this).data('url'),
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            $("#content").html(data);
        },
        error: function(response) {
           alert("ERROR:" + response.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

**Sample HTML:**

```
<button class="ajax-button" data-url="/account/create">Sign Up</button>
```

Comment: Great! Glad you found this useful. Enjoy!!

Comment: Can you explain how this part works? $(this).data('url')

Comment: Sure, `this` refers to the button that was clicked; therefore `$(this).data('url')` retrieves the data stored in `data-url` attribute of that button ... the `URL`. ... Does that help?

Comment: Would $(this).data('asdf') work for a data-asdf attribute? I guess my confusion is shouldn't $(this).data('url') be $(this).data('data-url')?

Comment: Yes it would work just fine. ... do not confuse it with `$(this).attr('data-url')` ... look up the API docs, they are pretty straight-forward.

Answer (score -1):

I'd have a click event listener for each element, then a function for the AJAX call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#home").click(function() {
        callAjax("/");
    });

    $("#login").click(function() {
        callAjax("/account/signin");
    });


    function callAjax(url) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            success: function(data) {
                $("#content").html(data);
            },
            error: function(response) {
                alert("ERROR:" + response.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
});
```